# pgfplot tick mark removed when x axis deleted

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks

I'm making a diagram with only a vertical axis and I want all the tick marks but the "0" tick mark does not occur because I removed the x axis. So I want that tick mark back and all thicker tick marks

[image: Missing tick mark]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{tick label style={color=white}} %lazy hack to hide tick labels
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-1, xmax=1,
ymin=-4, ymax=4,
xtick=\empty,
x axis line style={draw=none}
]
\addplot [only marks] table {
-0.5 3
-0.5 2
-0.5 -0.5
};
\addplot [only marks, mark=o] table {
0.5 0.5
0.5 -3.5
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if I have understood your request right, but did you mean the following?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % don't show the x-axis
        axis x line=none,
        % show centered y-axis
        axis y line=center,
        xmin=-1, xmax=1,
        ymin=-4, ymax=4,
        % don't show any labels on the yticks
        yticklabels={},
    ]
        \addplot [only marks] table {
            -0.5 3
            -0.5 2
            -0.5 -0.5
        };
        \addplot [only marks, mark=o] table {
            0.5 0.5
            0.5 -3.5
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]